# How to schedule qBittorrent to quit on Windows?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, qbittorrent

How can I schedule qBittorrent to quit the program gracefully at a certain hour every day?

I've tried the built-in scheduler, but it's too naive. Also had a look at the [WebUI API Documentation](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/WebUI-API-Documentation), but did not find any quit related command and it seems too complicated for my purpose. I just need it to quit or at least completely stop all downloads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although qBittorrent has a built-in scheduler, but currently it does not provide any way to schedule for program exit or even to set download limiter to 0KB/s. See [issue #6020](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/6020).

However one can use [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) and command line to achieve the same goal: Here is how: (I'm using qBittorrent v3.3.13)

**Disable any prompt that requires user interaction during exit:**

[image: qBitternt options screenshot]

- Goto Tools > Options > Behavior > Desktop
- Uncheck "Confirmation on exit when torrents are active."
- Also uncheck "Close qBittorrent to notification area." (We want it to quit, not just minimize itself.)

**Schedule a task for automatically exiting qBittorrent:**

- Press `Winkey + R`, type `taskschd.msc`, and press enter. (Or find and open task scheduler from the start menu.)
- Click on "Create basic task..." link and fill the form...
- Choose to "start a program" as action.
- "Program/Script": [`taskkill`](https://superuser.com/a/959365/340929)
- "Add arguments": `/im qbittorrent.exe`

**Linux users** should be able to do the same using the `kill` command and `crontab`. Or have a look at  [Is there a workaround for a lack of scheduler in qbittorrent?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59237/is-there-a-workaround-for-a-lack-of-scheduler-in-qbittorrent) on Linux & Unix Stack Exchange.